# jQuery slideToggle - hide when clicked again/other button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating toggle buttons that need some specific functions:

1) Show content on the first click (this works)

2) Hide content when you click on a different button (this works)

3) Hide content on the second click (this doesn't work)

Right now, if you click the same button twice it first slidesUp (because if you do click a different button, the previous content needs to be closed). Once it's up it then slidesDown, making it very jumpy.

Is there a way to make all 3 functions work?? 
Removing the " $(".assortiment").slideUp();" line fixes this jumpy problem, but that also stops function 2 from working...

```js
function assortiment(e){
  var assortimentid = e.id + "__js";
  if ($("#" + assortimentid).display = "block"){
    $(".assortiment").slideUp();
    $("#" + assortimentid).slideToggle();
  } else if ($("#" + assortimentid).display = "none"){
    $("#" + assortimentid).slideToggle();
  }
}
```

```css
.assortiment {
  display: none;
 }
 
.btn {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: lightblue;
 }
 .btn:hover {
   cursor: pointer
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn" id="section1" onclick="assortiment(this)">Section 1</div>
  <div class="btn" id="section2" onclick="assortiment(this)">Section 2</div>
  <div class="btn" id="section3" onclick="assortiment(this)">Section 3</div>
  
  <div class="assortiment" id="section1__js">
    <p>SOME CONTENT 1</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, aliquip apeirian dissentiunt ex pro. Ad choro facilis offendit mel, et quo quot democritum. Aliquip quaestio periculis ad eam, legere altera reprehendunt eu his. Cu has virtute pericula definitionem, cu facete conclusionemque has, cu errem accusamus duo.
</p>
  </div>
  <div class="assortiment" id="section2__js">
    <p>SOME CONTENT 2</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, aliquip apeirian dissentiunt ex pro. Ad choro facilis offendit mel, et quo quot democritum. Aliquip quaestio periculis ad eam, legere altera reprehendunt eu his. Cu has virtute pericula definitionem, cu facete conclusionemque has, cu errem accusamus duo.
</p>
  </div>
  <div class="assortiment" id="section3__js">
    <p>SOME CONTENT 3</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, aliquip apeirian dissentiunt ex pro. Ad choro facilis offendit mel, et quo quot democritum. Aliquip quaestio periculis ad eam, legere altera reprehendunt eu his. Cu has virtute pericula definitionem, cu facete conclusionemque has, cu errem accusamus duo.
</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: I would add an `toggledOpen` class when you toggle open - that way you can call `$(".toggledOpen").slideUp();` when you need to close whatever is already open.

Comment: you have a `=` in your condition which should be `==` or `===`

Comment: I didn't want to post this as an answer because I wanted to show you a simpler way to do the whole thing. [Here's how I'd do it (maybe)](https://jsfiddle.net/fgep04t3/). Few key points: `.assortiment` elements were given a parent, so that they are not siblings with the buttons. `targetElement` variable finds `.assortiment` element that matches the index of the clicked button. So this requires the contents to be in the right order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well try to avoid inline javascript..Write a separate function for `.btn` click to toggle display...use `slideToggle()` jQuery to toggle the same element...and `slideUp()` with `not()` to hide other elements

Also use `===` for comparison in condition,...`=` is used to assigned a value...

Also the `element.display = "none"` is not a valid statement, it should be like `element.css("display") === "none"`

```js
$(".btn").on("click", function() {
  var item = "#" + $(this).attr("id") + "__js"
  $(".assortiment").not(item).stop().slideUp();
  $(item).stop().slideToggle();
})
```

```css
.assortiment {
  display: none;
}

.btn {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn" id="section1">Section 1</div>
<div class="btn" id="section2">Section 2</div>
<div class="btn" id="section3">Section 3</div>

<div class="assortiment" id="section1__js">
  <p>SOME CONTENT 1</p>
</div>
<div class="assortiment" id="section2__js">
  <p>SOME CONTENT 2</p>
</div>
<div class="assortiment" id="section3__js">
  <p>SOME CONTENT 3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `.stop()` method which stops the currently-running animation on the matched element or in other words, prevents repetition:

```js
function assortiment(e){
  var assortimentid = e.id + "__js";
  if ($("#" + assortimentid).display = "block"){
    $(".assortiment").stop().slideUp();
    $("#" + assortimentid).stop().slideToggle();
  } else if ($("#" + assortimentid).display = "none"){
    $("#" + assortimentid).stop().slideToggle();
  }
}
```

```css
* {margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box} /* addition; more "fluent" */

.assortiment {
  display: none;
}

.btn {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn" id="section1" onclick="assortiment(this)">Section 1</div>
<div class="btn" id="section2" onclick="assortiment(this)">Section 2</div>
<div class="btn" id="section3" onclick="assortiment(this)">Section 3</div>

<div class="assortiment" id="section1__js">
  <p>SOME CONTENT 1</p>
</div>
<div class="assortiment" id="section2__js">
  <p>SOME CONTENT 2</p>
</div>
<div class="assortiment" id="section3__js">
  <p>SOME CONTENT 3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function assortiment(e){
  var assortimentid = e.id + "__js";
  if ($("#" + assortimentid).display == "block"){
    $(".assortiment").hide();
    $("#" + assortimentid).slideToggle();
  } else if ($("#" + assortimentid).display == "none"){
    $("#" + assortimentid).slideToggle();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your JS function defination to :

```
function assortiment(e){
  var assortimentid = e.id + "__js";
  $(".assortiment").not("#" + assortimentid).slideUp();
  $("#" + assortimentid).slideToggle(); 
}
```

**Full Snippet:**  and [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m127msuc/8/)

```js
function assortiment(e){
  var assortimentid = e.id + "__js";
  $(".assortiment").not("#" + assortimentid).slideUp();
  $("#" + assortimentid).slideToggle(); 
}
```

```css
.assortiment {
  display: none;
 }
 
.btn {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: lightblue;
 }
 .btn:hover {
   cursor: pointer
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn" id="section1" onclick="assortiment(this)">Section 1</div>
  <div class="btn" id="section2" onclick="assortiment(this)">Section 2</div>
  <div class="btn" id="section3" onclick="assortiment(this)">Section 3</div>
  
  <div class="assortiment" id="section1__js">
    <p>SOME CONTENT 1</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, aliquip apeirian dissentiunt ex pro. Ad choro facilis offendit mel, et quo quot democritum. Aliquip quaestio periculis ad eam, legere altera reprehendunt eu his. Cu has virtute pericula definitionem, cu facete conclusionemque has, cu errem accusamus duo.
</p>
  </div>
  <div class="assortiment" id="section2__js">
    <p>SOME CONTENT 2</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, aliquip apeirian dissentiunt ex pro. Ad choro facilis offendit mel, et quo quot democritum. Aliquip quaestio periculis ad eam, legere altera reprehendunt eu his. Cu has virtute pericula definitionem, cu facete conclusionemque has, cu errem accusamus duo.
</p>
  </div>
  <div class="assortiment" id="section3__js">
    <p>SOME CONTENT 3</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, aliquip apeirian dissentiunt ex pro. Ad choro facilis offendit mel, et quo quot democritum. Aliquip quaestio periculis ad eam, legere altera reprehendunt eu his. Cu has virtute pericula definitionem, cu facete conclusionemque has, cu errem accusamus duo.
</p>
  </div>
```